# Opencart 3 journal 3, have a different homepage layout with 2nd store on multistore

Tags: opencart, journal, multistore

Managed to setup a multistore on OC 3.0.3.2 using Journal Theme 3 and got it all functioning, the only issue I have is that the homepage is the same across both stores.

I have tried to create a new layout in Journal, then new information page and overwrite the layout but I have no idea how to make the second store show this information page instead of the default homepage.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Contact Journal 3 developers as the theme is paid...

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, incase anybody else faces this issue

Design > Layouts > edit layout you created for second homepage

Under Store select your second store, under route type

common/home